# Python: Get rid of punctuation marks with condition

Tags: python, regex, database, ascii

I can get rid of punctuations in my dataframe with this line:

```
df[column_name].replace(r'[^\s0-9a-zA-Z]+', r'', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

However there are some exceptions that I want to keep like:

I don't want to convert 15,00 to 1500. If there is a comma inside the text I want to keep it. Is there a simple way to do this. Thank you.

Comment: What's the input data and what's the expected output?

Comment: What makes 15,00 special?

Comment: "If there is a comma inside the text": inside text, or inside numbers? What if there's a space after the comma, like in a summation: "Choose from the numbers 10, 20, 30, 40, or 50"?

Comment: thank you for the replies. Yes the cases I want is the commas between numbers and it shouldn't consider the ones with commas only the ones that are like in the example I have given above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may avoid matching a comma in between digits when using your pattern if you append a `(?<!\d,(?=\d))` lookbehind:

```
r'[^\s0-9a-zA-Z](?<!\d,(?=\d))'
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCO6Om/1)

In short, `[^\s0-9a-zA-Z]` matches any char but whitespace and ASCII letters or digit. The `(?<!\d,(?=\d))` lookbehind fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is a digit, `,` and immediately to the right of the `,` there is a digit. The lookahead inside the lookbehind is necessary to make sure the comma is "mapped" in the lookbehind to `[^\s0-9a-zA-Z]` pattern only.

Also, there is a way to perform this check before matching the negated character class if you use `(?<!\d(?=,\d))[^\s0-9a-zA-Z]`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCO6Om/2). However, this approach is much costlier since the lookbehind is not "anchored" at any text or zero-width assertion.